# Nodemailer Path

Tags: node.js, express-handlebars

I just decided to use NodeMailer and it works well on localhost, but on the server, I don't know which path should I go to find the page's link. so here is the path in the app.js

```
// Static folder
app.use("/", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/views")));


// Body Parser Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get("/views", (req,res) =>{
    res.render("contact");
});
```

and in the views folder, I have the file contact.handlebars
I tried on the live server this links to find my web-form

mywebsite/views/contact.handlebars (this is downloading the file)

mywebsite/views/ (this shows just the index of the views)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xb7w0.jpg)

mywebsite/views/contact ( nothing )

Again, on my localhost, Everything works very well (localhost:3000/views)

I will be appreciated if someone would help me with this issue.

Comment: where do you store your server.js or app.js?

Comment: I'm storing the app.js in the root folder

Comment: Non-public files should be located above public root, for starters. `mywebsite/views/contact.handlebars` - this shouldn't be available from client side.

Comment: Do you have any error message or log from server? Looks like you already have a webserver and its not running your node app as the webserver